# What does the following expression does: x = (a1,a2,...,n);

Tags: c++, c

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) about sequence points and I saw this line:

> `i = (i, ++i, 1) + 1; // well defined (AFAIK)`

I was wondering how is the following syntax called and what are its effects?

`i = (a1, a2, ...,an);`

Comment: It evaluates each term sequentially and assigns the last term evaluated to `i`.

Comment: It’s the comma operator. It’s the lowest priority operator. There is a sequence point between evaluating the left and right sides of the operator.

Comment: Not every expression that is well defined should be written. This one is useless.

Comment: Unrelated, I think it is still UB. Because the left `i = ` is unsequenced in relation to the `(i,`, regardless of the commas. You'd have to write something like `i = (0, i, ++i,0);`

Comment: I believe the validity of this depends on whether you're programming in C or new-ish C++ or old-ish C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the comma operator for `int` operands, together with grouping through parentheses, which is always allowed. First,

```
(i, ++i, 1)
```

evaluates `i`, then `++i`, then `1` and returns the result of the last expression (which is `1`). Then

```
(i, ++i, 1) + 1
```

is the same as

```
1 + 1;
```

which results in `2`, so `i` is set to `2` here. Note that without the parentheses, the result would in most cases not be the same, as the comma operator has the lowest possible precedence (thanks to @dbush for helping me out here in the comments).

Comment: The result without parenthesis is *not* the same.  In that case the statement parses as `(i = i), ++i, (1 + 1);`, which results in the prior value of `i` getting incremented.

Comment: @dbush You're right, thanks I was thinking through this code with a contrived initial value of `i` as `1`, but that's bogus...